# System of linear equations with some non-negativity constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I've a system of equations $Ax=0$ which is subject to the constraint that the **first few components of the unknown vector x is non-negative** (No constraint on remaining components of x vector). The $A$ matrix has more number of columns than rows.

I want to solve for "**ALL Independent**" $x$ vectors (A set of vectors which are feasible and independent and this set contains maximum number of possible vectors). How do I do this?

Is it possible to convert this into a Linear Programming Problem and use simplex method to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: How many equations? How many unknowns? How many nonnegativity constraints?

Comment: But, in general, not all unknowns are required to be nonnegative?

Comment: The solution set is not a subspace, so what do you mean by "orthonormal basis of the solution set"?

Answer (score 1):

Given a fat matrix $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$, we form an underdetermined system $\mathrm A \mathrm x = \mathrm 0_m$. If the first $n_1 \leq n$ entries of $\mathrm x$ must be nonnegative, then an admissible solution can be found via the linear program

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mathrm c^T \mathrm x\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm A \mathrm x = \mathrm 0_m\\ & \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_{n_1} & \mathrm O\end{bmatrix} \mathrm x \geq 0_{n_1}\end{array}$$

where $\mathrm c \in \mathbb R^{n}$ is arbitrary.

Comment: You have a linear system with inequality constraints. The feasible region is a polytope. If you pick different $\mathrm c$'s each time you solve the LP, you get various vertices of the polytope. If you always use the same $\mathrm c$, you always get the same vertex. The feasible region may also be unbounded.

Comment: @Dheeraj You can change the objective function. For example,
$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \| \mathrm x \|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & \mathrm A \mathrm x = \mathrm 0_m\\ & \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm I_{n_1} & \mathrm O\end{bmatrix} \mathrm x \geq 0_{n_1}\end{array}$$ is a quadratic program (QP). The minimum is not necessarily attained at a vertex.